# Usage of onpopstate with Balupton's History.js to go back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

my objective is to store the current state of a web site, such that I can return to that state via pressing the browsers back button. Currently, I've achieved this using pushState and popState using the HTML5 native functions as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    $("#element").load($(this).attr('href') + ' #otherElement');
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
    previous_page = location.href;
    window.history.pushState({page: $(this).index()}, $(this).html(), $(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  window.popupstate = function(e) {
    location.reload();
  }
</script>
```

That piece of code works as expected in Firefox 4. However, in Chrome, the page reloads permanently. Thus, I would like to use Balupton's History.js library to run the code snippet in all browser, but I found the example on Balupton's page not very helpful.

I've tried the following (which does not work):

```
var History = window.History;
History.pushState({state:'root'},'root',$(this).attr('href'));

$("a").click(function(e) {
  $("#element").load($(this).attr('href') + ' #otherElement');
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
  History.pushState({state:$(this).attr('href')},$(this).attr('href'),$(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
    if (State.title == 'root') {
        History.back();
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a working solution for my problem. Since I am loosing the bindings while replacing an entire DOM path, I need just to hide/show the elements as follows:

```
var History = window.History;

$("a").live('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('href').startsWith('corpus-')) {
        $("#element").hide();
        $("#newElement").load($(this).attr('href') + ' #otherElement');
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
        History.pushState({state:$(this).attr('href')},$(this).attr('href'),$(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    }
});

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
    var State = History.getState();
    History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
    $("#element").toggle();
    $("#newElement").toggle();
});
```

The solution is not quite ideal, yet.